# Angular change detection is not working after AngularFireAuth signInWithPopup

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I call AngularFireAuth signInWithPopup like below and on its success, route to another component but in that changes are not detected.

Find complete code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdissue

The first screen has two buttons - 'Go to comp2 without login' & 'Go to comp2 after login'
First click on the button 'Go to comp2 without login' to go to second screen where two buttons & a count text are there.

Click on the Increment button will increment the count. This is the working fine scenario.

Click 'Go back' to back to screen one then click on the button 'Go to comp2 after login' which will show a popup to login through gmail. After login it will automatically route to screen two.
You may use the credentials cdissue@gmail.com & @ngularTest to login using gmail

Now the count is not displayed or click on increment doesn't show the count and this is the error scenario

```
Observable.fromPromise(
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
    )
    .pipe(
      first(),
      map( authData => {
        this.router.navigate(['comp2'])
      })
    ).subscribe();
```

Comment: I got `Incorrect password` when used `cdtest@gmail.com & @ngularTest`

Comment: sorry, email is cdissue@gmail.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you leave angular zone after login.

The solution is to run code inside angular zone:

```
constructor(
    ...
    private zone: NgZone
 ) { }
...
...
 .pipe(
    first(),
    map(authData => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.goToComp2();
      });
    })
  ).subscribe();
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdissue-udn2gt?file=src/app/comp2/comp2.component.ts)**

Comment: Ok, now got the problem signInWithPopup is run outside of the NgZone. Thank you!